# Making a newcommand (nonexisitng) congruence theorem AngleAngleAngle

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am trying to build a macro for the non-existent congruence theorem WWW (AAA?), where of course one must specify a side a (By the way, SideSideSide works well).
Someone asked for a minimal working example. The question is closed so i do not know how to publish otherwise than editing the question. May be some packages are useless here, but i tried to minimize. This here works fine by me.
I solved the problem as i mentioned in my own answer by using degrees to calculate the lenghts of the sides.
Now the commented "clip" in SSS does not work, but i will try to fix this later.
I hope editing the question was allowed.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}  %für logische Symbole


\usepackage{tikz}    
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}% Für Wellenlinien u.a.
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}                     %für Schaltungen
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usepackage[RPvoltages, europeanresistors, europeanvoltages]{circuitikz}     %für Schaltungen
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, graphs, intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap, trees}




\usepackage{mathtools} %wird hier im speziellen benötigt um\abs zu definieren
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns} % Hinzufügen der patterns-Bibliothek
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
%\usepackage{alphabeta}


\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{fp}%für Rechungen mit Variablen
\usepackage[round-mode = places, round-precision = 2]{siunitx}

\newcommand{\SSS}[4][1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1]
        % Definiere die Punkte A und B
        \coordinate[label=left:$A$] (A) at (0,0);
        \coordinate[label=right:$B$] (B) at (#2,0);
        
        % Zeichne die Seite c
        \draw[blue] (A) -- (B) node[midway, below] {c = #2};
        
        % Zeichne die Kreise um A und B
        \draw[name path=circleA, green] (A) circle (#3);
        \draw[name path=circleB, red] (B) circle (#4);
        
        % Finde den Schnittpunkt der beiden Kreise und nenne ihn C
        \path[name intersections={of=circleA and circleB, by={C}}];
        
        % Berechne die Winkel
        \pgfmathsetmacro\angleA{acos((#2^2+#4^2-#3^2)/(2*#2*#4))}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\angleB{acos((#2^2+#3^2-#4^2)/(2*#2*#3))}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\angleC{acos((#3^2+#4^2-#2^2)/(2*#3*#4))}
        
        % Runde die Winkel auf volle Grad
        \pgfmathround{\angleA}
        \let\angleARounded\pgfmathresult
        \pgfmathround{\angleB}
        \let\angleBRounded\pgfmathresult
        \pgfmathround{\angleC}
        \let\angleCRounded\pgfmathresult
        
        % Berechne die Höhe
        \pgfmathsetmacro\height{#2*sin(\angleA)}
        
        % Setze den Clip-Befehl
        %\clip (-1,-1) rectangle (#2+1,\height+1);
        
        % Zeichne die Seiten a und b
        \draw[red] (B) -- (C) node[midway, above right] {a = #3};
        \draw[green] (C) -- (A) node[midway, above left] {b = #4};
        
        % Zeichne die Winkel
        \shorthandoff{"}
        \draw pic["$\alpha = \angleARounded^\circ$", draw=orange, <->, pic text options={yshift=0.1cm}, angle eccentricity=0.8, angle radius=1cm] {angle=B--A--C};
        \draw pic["$\beta = \angleBRounded^\circ$", draw=orange, <->, pic text options={yshift=0.1cm}, angle eccentricity=0.8, angle radius=1cm] {angle=C--B--A};
        \draw pic["$\gamma = \angleCRounded^\circ$", draw=orange, <->, pic text options={yshift=0.1cm}, angle eccentricity=0.8, angle radius=1cm] {angle=A--C--B};
        \shorthandon{"}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}


\newcommand{\WWW}[5][1]{
    % Überprüfe, ob die Summe der Winkel 180° beträgt
    \pgfmathparse{#2+#3+#4}
    \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=180pt
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1, transform shape]
        % Definiere die Punkte B und C
        \coordinate[label=left:$B$] (B) at (0,0);
        \coordinate[label=right:$C$] (C) at (#5,0);
        
        % Zeichne die Seite a
        \draw[red] (B) -- (C) node[midway, below] {a = #5};
        
        % Berechne die Seiten b und c mit dem Sinussatz
        \pgfmathsetmacro\sideB{#5*sin(#3)/sin(#2)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\sideC{#5*sin(#4)/sin(#2)}
        \message{Seite a = #5, Seite b = \sideB, Seite c = \sideC}
        
        % Zeichne die Winkelhalbierenden
        \pgfmathsetmacro\langesC{\sideC+1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\langesB{\sideB+1}
        \draw[name path=angleB, blue] (B) -- ++(#3:\langesC cm);
        \draw[name path=angleC, green] (C) -- ++({180-#4}:\langesB cm);
        
        % Finde den Schnittpunkt der beiden Winkel und nenne ihn A
        \path[name intersections={of=angleB and angleC, by={A}}];
        \node[above] at (A) {$A$};
        
        % Zeichne die Seiten b und c
        \draw[blue] (A) -- (B) node[midway, above left] {c = \pgfmathprintnumber{\sideC}};
        \draw[green] (A) -- (C) node[midway, above right] {b = \pgfmathprintnumber{\sideB}};
        
        % Zeichne die Innenwinkel
        \shorthandoff{"}
        \draw pic["$\alpha = #2^\circ$", draw=orange, <->, pic text options={yshift=0.1cm}, angle eccentricity=0.8, angle radius=1cm] {angle=B--A--C};
        \draw pic["$\beta = #3^\circ$", draw=orange, <->, pic text options={yshift=0.1cm}, angle eccentricity=0.8, angle radius=1cm] {angle=C--B--A};
        \draw pic["$\gamma = #4^\circ$", draw=orange, <->, pic text options={yshift=0.1cm}, angle eccentricity=0.8, angle radius=1cm] {angle=A--C--B};
        \shorthandon{"}
        \message{Winkel #2 = #2, Winkel #3 = #3, Winkel #4 = #4}
        \message{Seite a = #5, Seite b = \sideB, Seite c = \sideC}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \else
    nicht zu konstruieren
    \fi
}
\newcommand{\WSW}[4][1]{%#1=Skalierung #2=beta, #3=a, #4=gamma
    % Standardmäßig wird die Seite a gezeichnet, also werden beta und gamma angegeben und alpha wird erstmal berechnet.
    \pgfmathsetmacro\alph{180-#2-#4}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1, transform shape]
        % Definiere die Punkte B und C
        \coordinate[label=left:$B$] (B) at (0,0);
        \coordinate[label=right:$C$] (C) at (#3,0);
        
        % Zeichne die Seite a
        \draw[red] (B) -- (C) node[midway, below] {a = #3};
        
        % Berechne die Seiten b und c mit dem Sinussatz
        \pgfmathsetmacro\sideB{#3*sin(#2)/sin(\alph)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\sideC{#3*sin(#4)/sin(\alph)}
        %\message{Seite a = #4, Seite b = \sideB, Seite c = \sideC}
        
        % Zeichne die Winkelhalbierenden
        \pgfmathsetmacro\langesC{\sideC+1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\langesB{\sideB+1}
        \draw[name path=angleB, blue] (B) -- ++(#2:\langesC cm);
        \draw[name path=angleC, green] (C) -- ++({180-#4}:\langesB cm);
        
        % Finde den Schnittpunkt der beiden Winkelhalbierenden und nenne ihn A
        \path[name intersections={of=angleB and angleC, by={A}}];
        \node[above] at (A) {$A$};
        
        % Zeichne die Seiten b und c
        \draw[blue] (A) -- (B) node[midway, above left] {c = \pgfmathprintnumber{\sideC}};
        \draw[green] (A) -- (C) node[midway, above right] {b = \pgfmathprintnumber{\sideB}};
        
        % Zeichne die Innenwinkel
        \shorthandoff{"}
        \draw pic["$\alpha = \alph^\circ$", draw=orange, <->, pic text options={yshift=0.1cm}, angle eccentricity=0.8, angle radius=1cm] {angle=B--A--C};
        \draw pic["$\beta = #2^\circ$", draw=orange, <->, pic text options={yshift=0.1cm}, angle eccentricity=0.8, angle radius=1cm] {angle=C--B--A};
        \draw pic["$\gamma = #4^\circ$", draw=orange, <->, pic text options={yshift=0.1cm}, angle eccentricity=0.8, angle radius=1cm] {angle=A--C--B};
        \shorthandon{"}
        \message{Winkel \alpha = \alph, Winkel \beta = #2, Winkel \gamma = #4}
        \message{Seite a = #3, Seite b = \sideB, Seite c = \sideC}
        
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
}




\begin{document}
    \WWW{30}{40}{110}{4}\\
    \WSW{50}{5}{60}\\
    \SSS{3}{4}{5}\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you give us an ECM?

Comment: @AlainMatthes What's an ECM?  On this site, we will often ask for a MWE (minimal working example).  Is ECM an acronym for a similar concept?

Comment: @Teepeemm Sorry In french `Exemple complet minimal` similar concept

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion: Using degrees! I tried several times with radiant and degrees but didn't work either, seems that i had several other issues that were solved "by chance/ randomly".
This works fine:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\sideB{#5*sin(#3)/sin(#2)}
```

Thanks for your attention!
Greetings
Patrick